# Как заставить nginx запускать lua скрипты через luaJIT?

Tags: nginx, lua

Хочу возложить логику проверки jwt на плечи nginx:
https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt

Сервер имеет следующую конфигурацию:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name test;

        location / {
                access_by_lua '
                local jwt = require("nginx-jwt")
                jwt.auth()
                ';
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1338;
        }

}
```

В nginx.conf указал расположение lua-скриптов:

```
lua_package_path "/opt/test/?.lua;;";
```

Перезагружаю nginx, обращаюсь по http:

```
$ curl test
```

Получаю 500 ошибку, в логах nginx:

```
2016/09/27 15:01:57 [error] 25541#0: *399 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /opt/test/resty/evp.lua:4: module 'ffi' not found:
```

На Lua не кодил. Выяснилось, что есть две среды исполнения Lua: это собственно lua и luajit. Выяснилось, что ffi модуль - это какая-то штука с возможностью исполнения Си кода, и исполняется только посредством luajit. В моем случае скрипты выполняются посредством lua, и это завершается такой вот ошибкой (проверял в REPL).

Уже все излазил. Поставил OpenResty дистрибутив, собрал, установил - эффекта нет. Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы nginx запускал эти скрипты посредством luaJIT ?

**UPD**

Мой nginx использует lua (не luaJIT):

```
# ldd /usr/sbin/nginx | grep -i lua
liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0  (0x00007f64935f7000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть решение не чисто по вопросу: можно поставить https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb. Данный модуль является *почти* полной версией ffi для lua (есть одна нереализованая возможность, но довольно редко используемая). Собирать с либами lua 5.1 (у вас именно он), инструкции в репозитории.

Answer (score 1):

content_by_lua_file , но к этому надо еще и дефолтный тип ввести

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста более развернутый ответ